# cloud firestore search by child value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am searching a record in child level using one of the key called email ID, but it always returning null. Below is my collection data base and Query.

[image]

```
exports.authVerfication = functions.https.onRequest((req,res)=>{
if(req.method!=='POST'){
    return res.status(500).json({
        message:'Not allowed'
    });
}

 const p3= db.collection('Users').where('state', '==', 'Kar').get();
 const p2= p3.then(snapshot =>{
    if (!snapshot.exists) {
        res.status(204).send({message:'No users found'});
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(snapshot.data());
      }
    })
```

Comment: What do you mean by "returning null". How do you display the results? In other words, what is after the `.get()`??

Comment: const p3= db.collection('Users').where('state', '==', 'Kar').get();
     const p2= p3.then(snapshot =>{
        if (!snapshot.exists) {
            res.status(204).send({message:'No users found'});
          } else {
            res.status(200).send(snapshot.data());
          }
        })

This is how i m returning an API results.

Comment: Can you modify your original question with this part of the code? Thx

Comment: Yep, it works by adding doc.data() as you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

By doing:

```
 const p3 = db.collection('Users').where('state', '==', 'Kar').get();
 const p2 = p3.then(snapshot =>{})
```

the `snapshot` you get is a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) (see [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get)) and there is no `exists` property for such an object. You should use the [`empty`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#empty) property.

---

As said in a comment to your question (that I deleted) you can test that the query returns a result with:

```
const p3 = db.collection('Users').where('state', '==', 'Kar').get();
const p2 = p3.get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```